# Doxygen not documenting variables when the type is defined type

Tags: c, doxygen

I have a file whose name is "myfile.c". At the top of this file I have a documentation block

```
/*!
* \file myfile.c
* \ingroup mygroup
* \defgroup mygroup This is the foo module
* \brief Module containing foo code
*/
```

Within that file I have the following:

```
/*!
* \brief blabla
* \ingroup mygroup
*/
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t foo1, foo2, foo3;
} mytype_t
```

The documentation for this structure shows up in my doxygen output for mygroup. However, when I create a variable of type mytype_t, its documentation isn't being output.

```
/*!
* \brief blabla
* \ingroup mygroup
*/
static mytype_t volatile my_variable=
{
    .foo1 = 1u,
    .foo2 = 2u,
    .foo3 = 3u
};
```

I have tried adding the tag

```
\var my_variable
```

This does not seem to do anything.

Am I missing something?

documentation for my_variable isn't just missing from the group - it doesn't exist in my doxygen output at all. Also, there is nothing in my output log w/ my variables name - warning, error, or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nm, I was being silly. Those variables are static and I didn't have EXTRACT_STATIC SET to yes.